# want to create events in calendar....using Fullcalendar.min.js....how to create form in prompt box

Tags: fullcalendar

```
$('#V2_calenderEvents').live('click',function(){
    var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();


$('#main-content').empty();
$('#main-content').append(

 "<div class='calendar'  style='height:555px;width:100%;margin-top:0px;'>"+


         "</br>"+
        "<div class='calendar' id='calendar'>" +
        "</div>"+
        "</div>"

    );
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var abc = {
                state0: {
                    title: '<p><i class="fontello-icon-edit"></i> New Event</p>',
                     html: 
                         '<div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" id="eventtitle" class="input-block-level" type="text" name="eventtitle" placeholder="Title">'+
                         '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<div class="row-fluid">'+
                             '<div class="control-group span4"><div class="controls"><input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" id="evendate" class="input-block-level  " disabled type="text" name="eventdate" placeholder="">'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<div class="control-group span4"><div class="controls"><input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" id="startime" class="input-block-level " type="time" name="Startime" placeholder="Start Time">'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                              '<div class="control-group span4"><div class="controls"><input id="endtime" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" class="input-block-level " type="time" name="Endtime" placeholder="End Time">'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><select id="notification Type"  style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px"class="selectpicker-boo input-block-level" name="Notificationtype">'+
                             '<option value="dntnotification"> Notification type</option>'+
                            '<option value="dntnotification">iCal Email</option>'+
                            '<option value="dntnotification">Simple Email</option>'+
                            '<option value="dntnotification">Do Not Send Notification</option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+

                            '<div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><input id="eventdescription" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" class="input-block-level" type="text" name="Descripption" placeholder="Description">'+
                         '</div>'+

                             '</div>'+
                            '<div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><select id="eventshareType"  style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px"class="selectpicker-boo input-block-level" name="Notificationtype">'+
                            '<option value="0">Share With</option>'+
                            '<option value="eventindvidual">Indvidual</option>'+
                            '<option value="eventgroup">Course</option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                            '<div id="eventind" style="display:none" class="control-group"><div class="controls"><input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" id="evenshareind" class="input-block-level" type="text" >'+
                         '</div>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<div id="eventgroup" style="display:none"class="control-group"><div class="controls"><select id="eventsharegroup"  style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-weight:bold;font-size:12px"class="selectpicker-boo input-block-level" name="Notificationtype">'+
                             '<option value="0">Select</option>'+

                        '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+

                             '</div>',


                    buttons:{Save:1 },
                    //focus: "input[name='fname']",
                    submit:function(e,v,m,f){ 

                        title=f.eventtitle;
                        e.preventDefault();

                        newtitle = title;


                        if(newtitle.length==0)

                        {
                       bootbox.alert("<b>Title Must Be Filled Out</b>");
                        $.prompt.show();


                        }
                        $.prompt.close();






                         if (newtitle) {
                                   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                           {
                                                   title: newtitle,
                                                   start: eventdate,
                                                   end: end,
                                                   allDay: allDay
                                           },
                                           true // make the event "stick"
                                   );
                           }

                        /*if(newtitle){

                             var rootURL = "services/CalendarService/updateCalendarEvent/"+ espanUserId+"/"+espanUserRole+"/"+title+"/"+eventdate;

                            $.get(rootURL,function(data) {
                            });
                           }*/

                           calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                    }
                },

            };

        //var title = prompt("Add Events");
            var title = prompt(abc);
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                true // make the event "stick"
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
            end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            start: new Date(y, m, 28),
            end: new Date(y, m, 29),
            url: 'http://google.com/'
        }
    ]
});
});
```

// When we click on a particular date on calendar a prompt box opens, i want to create a form in this prompt box, i have written the code for a form in variable, when i pass this variable in prompt box, it returns me object object....how to resolve this...i'm using fullcalendar.min.js

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here can be done by `renderEvent` check docs here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/ , just create an function and pass parameters to it `start` & `end`.

Comment: thanks but i don't need this, i have to create a form in prompt box, how can i do that...